# Using same function to handle different classes

Tags: c++, oop, class

I have two classes B and C- both are monsters within my (very primitive) game.  I have a function called MOVE, which at the moment just changes the X and Y coordinates of the Monster. Both B and C are derived from A; so A has the X and Y coordinates, and B and C have other attributes, such as speed, and attack.

Is there a way that I can set up one function that will allow me to pass either B or C (As they both need to be able to move..), in other words It doesn't matter if the monster that is being moved is B or C - but it will treat them in the same way ?

I was thinking about passing the class A, but I cannot get this to work! :-(. (maybe it's just me being extremely inexperienced!)

Many thanks - :-)

KJ

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I was using C++. That has now been added. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: This is called polymorphism, and your first instinct was, at least partially, correct.  Your function should be implemented in terms of `A`, but to work properly you need to pass it in as a reference (`A&`) or (less preferred) a pointer (`A*`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement move as a function of a. Then both b and c will have move functions and you can then use polymorphism to move both b and c as children of a.

For an answer that is more to the point, some code would really help, also of course the language you are using. The way you describe it, some things don't sound like they are implemented well in respect to OO.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This is my first real 'project'. Just starting out in the C++ world.

Answer (score 1):

Use can implement `move` method in parent class `A`:

```
class A {
  private:
    int X;
    int Y;

  public:
    A() { X = 0; Y = 0; }

    inline void move (int dx, int dy) {
      X += dx;
      Y += dy;
      std::cout << "Moved to " << X << "," << Y << std::endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {};

class C : public A {};
```

You can then use those classes:

```
A objB;
A objC;

objB.move(0,1);
objB.move(0,3);
objC.move(2,0);
```

This code would print:

```
Moved to 0,1
Moved to 0,4
Moved to 2,0
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but in this context `A` is _not_ abstract.  An abstract class has at least one _pure_ virtual function.

Comment: That doesn't even compile.

Comment: @KerrekSB - true, I wrote it without compiling first, then I decided to expand it to form a complete class. Even now I skipped the main() as it's not the point here. But you're right, I made that clear by separating two code blocks.